# cellを左にスワイプさせ「delete」文字を「削除」文字に変更して表示させたい

Tags: swift

```
extension AddViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let topicArray = us.array(forKey: topicArrayKey) as! [String]
        return topicArray.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let topicArray = us.array(forKey: topicArrayKey) as! [String]
        cell.textLabel!.text = topicArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            var topicArray = us.array(forKey: topicArrayKey) as! [String]
            topicArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            us.set(topicArray, forKey: topicArrayKey)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: こちらが参考になるでしょう。https://qiita.com/eKushida/items/bf02d0b44eca14cfbfdc

Answer (score 1):

もしユーザーの言語設定に関係なく常に「削除」というテキストを表示したいのであれば、`tableView(_:titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt:)`というデリゲートメソッドを実装して、表示したい文字列を返します。

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String? {
  ...
  ...
  return "削除"
}
```

ただ、ユーザーの言語設定によって自動的にシステムが提供する翻訳テキストを表示したいのであれば、上記のデリゲートを実装する必要はなく、単にそのプロジェクトに日本語のローカライゼーションの設定を追加すればいいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

特にローカライズのテキストを用意する必要はなく、日本語のローカライズの設定があれば、ユーザーの使用言語が日本語の場合にはその部分は「削除」が表示されます。他の言語もサポートするのであれば必要な言語のローカライゼーションの設定を追加します。